# Where can I see Intel® Virtual RAID on CPU logs on Windows Server 2019 and check if there is any error on any Raid 1 disks?

Tags: raid, software-raid, raid-1, windows-server-2019

I have the below system and i noticed that it is repairing the raid right now.

I want to be sure that there is no bad sectors on any of the raid disk but I don't know how can I do that

Here all the relevant information

System Report

```
System Information
OS name:  Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard
OS version:  10.0.17763  17763
System name:  MONSTERMMORPG
System manufacturer:  Supermicro
System model:  X9DR3-F
Processor:  GenuineIntel Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7 2.001  GHz
Processor:  GenuineIntel Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7 2.001  GHz
BIOS:  American Megatrends Inc., 3.0a

Intel® Virtual RAID on CPU Information
User interface version:  7.6.0.1016
Language:  English (United States)
Intel controller:  SATA (AHCI)
Number of SATA ports:  6
RAID option ROM version:  3.7.0.1049
SATA driver version:  7.6.0.1020
ISDI version:  7.6.0.1016

Storage System Information
RAID Configuration

Array Name:  SATA_Array_0000
Size:  1,863.03 GB
Available space:  93.23 GB
Number of volumes:  1
Volume member:  raid1
Number of array disks:  2
Array disk:  x
Array disk:  x
Disk data cache:  Enabled

Volume name:  raid1
Status:  Verifying and repairing 21% complete
Type:  RAID 1
Size:  884.90 GB
System volume:  Yes  
Data strip size:  N/A
Write-back cache:  Disabled
Initialized:  Yes  
Blocks with media errors:  0
Physical sector size:  512 Bytes
Logical sector size:  512 Bytes

Hardware Information

Controller name:  Intel(R) C600+/C220+ series chipset SATA RAID Controller
Type:  SATA
Mode:  RAID
Number of volumes:  1
Volume:  raid1
Number of spares:  0
Number of available disks:  2
Rebuild on Hot Insert:  Disabled
Manufacturer:  8086
Model number:  2826
Product revision:  6
Direct attached disk:  x
Direct attached disk:  x
Direct attached disk:  WD-x
Direct attached disk:  x

Disk on Controller 0, Port 0
Status:  Normal
Type:  SATA SSD
Location type:  Internal
Usage:  Array disk
Size:  932 GB
System disk:  No
Disk data cache:  Enabled
Command queuing:  NCQ
Model:  Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB                 
Serial number:  x
SCSI device ID:  0
Firmware:  EMT02B6Q
Physical sector size:  512 Bytes
Logical sector size:  512 Bytes

Disk on Controller 0, Port 1
Status:  Normal
Type:  SATA SSD
Location type:  Internal
Usage:  Array disk
Size:  932 GB
System disk:  No
Disk data cache:  Enabled
Command queuing:  NCQ
Model:  Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB                 
Serial number:  x
SCSI device ID:  1
Firmware:  EMT01B6Q
Physical sector size:  512 Bytes
Logical sector size:  512 Bytes

Disk on Controller 0, Port 2
Status:  Normal
Type:  SATA disk
Location type:  Internal
Usage:  Available
Size:  932 GB
System disk:  No
Disk data cache:  Enabled
Command queuing:  NCQ
Model:  WDC WD1003FBYZ-010FB0                   
Serial number:  WD-x
SCSI device ID:  2
Firmware:  01.01V03
Physical sector size:  512 Bytes
Logical sector size:  512 Bytes

Disk on Controller 0, Port 3
Status:  Normal
Type:  SATA SSD
Location type:  Internal
Usage:  Available
Size:  466 GB
System disk:  No
Disk data cache:  Enabled
Command queuing:  NCQ
Model:  Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB               
Serial number:  x
SCSI device ID:  3
Firmware:  RVT04B6Q
Physical sector size:  512 Bytes
Logical sector size:  512 Bytes

Empty port
Port:  4
Controller SATA (AHCI)
Port location:  Internal

Empty port
Port:  5
Controller SATA (AHCI)
Port location:  Internal
```

Comment: Start by waiting until the array is rebuilt. Don’t do anything else on that machine.

Comment: @Ramhound ye it is being done. After that how can I be sure both drives are fine to go or need to be replaced?

Comment: You can’t determine anything until the rebuild is done

Comment: @Ramhound ok it is completed. It doesn't show any errors. Now how do I proceed to verify each raid disk health?

Comment: The RAID controller should handle that task.  Which is the reason you waited.  The controller will poll the S.M.A.R.T attributes of each disk in the array; when and if the controller determines a disk is in danger, it should indicate the health of the array is in danger. In theory you are notified before the disk has actually failed and been ejected out of the array.

Comment: @Ramhound yes it shows everything ok. i also enabled read patrol. however I wish I could check smart of each disk myself even do bad sector scan if possible